# Concatenate result of two select statements

Tags: sql, oracle

My query is something like:

```
concatenate( 
 (select col1 from table1) , ( select col1.substr(1,<tillENd>) ) 
)
```

This works fine if both sub-selects return one row and one column. In my case, both will give multiple rows but one column.

I want to concatenate them row-wise. How can I do this?

---

Update:  complete queries are something like the following.

Query 1:

```
select col3 
from tabl2 
where col2 in (select substr(A,1,instr(A,'_',-1)-1) 
               from ( select substr(col1,1,instr(col1,'/')-1) as A 
                      from ( select col1 from tabl1 ) 

               ) 
           )
```

seond select query:

```
select substr(col1,instr(col1,'/')) as A1 
from ( select col1 
from tabl1 )
```

Comment: can you put an example with some rows per table and desired output?

Comment: Is there any relationship between table1 and table2?

Comment: this question seems to be incomplete

Comment: First select query is like : 
select col3 from tabl2 where col2 in (select substr(A,1,instr(A,'_',-1)-1) from ( select substr(col1,1,instr(col1,'/')-1) as A from ( select col1 from tabl1 ) ) )

seond select query is like : 
select substr(col1,instr(col1,'/')) as A1 from ( select col1 from tabl1 )

And I want to concatenate the result of above two.

Comment: @Ertunc : i have given both my select query. Second select query is producing more than 1 row and i am not able to handle multiple rows.

Answer (score 9):

```
select ...
from   ...
union all
select ...
from   ...
```

Or if you use UNION instead of UNION ALL the complete result set is subject to a DISTINCT operation.

Comment: It displaying output of both queries in 2 rows.  I want to concatenate  the result of both queries in a single row.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have provided some sample queries it is easier for us to offer a solution.

Regarding your additional requirement, I assume you don't want to match the void strings, so the easiest thing is to filter them out in the sub-query.

```
with data as ( select substr(col1,1,instr(col1,'/')-1) as A
               , substr(col1,instr(col1,'/')) as A1 
            from tabl1
           where instr(col1,'/') > 0 )
select tabl2.col3
       , data.A1
from data
      join tabl2
     on tabl2.col2 = substr(data.A,1,instr(data.A,'_',-1)-1);
```

Comment: hi .. after much trials .. i got my query .. some thing like :

select col3||(SUBSTR (col1, INSTR (col1, '/'))) 
          PATH 
  FROM table1 ,table2 
  where col2||'_'||col4 = SUBSTR (col1, 1, INSTR (col1, '/') - 1) ;

But i am facing one issue here..

Problem : if i dont find '/' inside col1, then it returns 0.. and because of this zero substr gives me the string from starting, that i dont want.

I want if '/' is not present gives void string.
Any suggestion will be appreciable.

Comment: I'm not going to bother editing my query to match your revisions - it's the principle that matters here.  However, if you can't adapt my suggestion to your actual situation then you must post more details: table structures, sample data and desired output.  It's hard for us to give complete solutions when you don't provide the whole picture.

Comment: I appreciate your voice of concern @APC . Might be I have not put my question in right way. sorry for that .. Now or after i'll learn this also. I have asked one subquestion regarding this which has solved my problem. so, really thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try [LISTAGG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions089.htm#CJABDFBD) function. Also see [COLLECT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions031.htm#i1271564) function.

Then concatenate results.